# Not able to rename document of Draft envelope

Tags: docusignapi

Our application creates a draft envelope from template using docusign rest API. Based on the user input application renaming the document and send envelope for signing.

We are using API `PUT "docusignUrl/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents"` to rename the documents of a draft envelope from past 10 months. It was working till yesterday. All of sudden today it is not renaming the document. It is keeping document name as template name itself.

Can somebody please help me to rename the document. I am using demo.docusign.net

Following are the request and response contents.

Url: https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/1234/envelopes/a499c33a-94c6-46e1-a0f2-bf5cd368529b/documents

```
Request body:
{"documents":[
    {"name":"150821183100_Order-Sign_companyc_P",
    "documentId":"1",
    "order":"1",
    "pages":"1",
    "type":"content",
    "uri":"/envelopes/a499c33a-94c6-46e1-a0f2-bf5cd368529b/documents/1"
    }]
}

Response Body:
{
  "envelopeId": "a499c33a-94c6-46e1-a0f2-bf5cd368529b",
  "envelopeDocuments": [
    {
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "SOMA_Sign_OrderManagement.pdf",
      "uri": "/envelopes/a499c33a-94c6-46e1-a0f2-bf5cd368529b/documents/1",
      "order": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your previous behavior is the desired behavior.

This is a bug that is being looked into by DocuSign, I'll update this answer if I get any additional information.

**UPDATE: The issue has been resolved and is working as intended in Demo once again.**

Comment: This has been fixed in demo.docusign.net, please test again